# Gunicorn error: unrecognized arguments wsgi:application

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I was trying to run Django in Nginx with the centos7 platform and also I am a newbie to it. After some time, I configured Django in Nginx with the help of the gunicorn service, But suddenly gunicorn service stopped with an unrecognized argument error (WSGI).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvO9n.png)

and my gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/websitehg/websites/qatarfactory/qf_project
ExecStart=/home/websitehg/websites/qatarfactory/qf_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --reload true --bind unix:/home/websitehg/websites/qatarfactory/qf_project/qf_project.sock qf_project.wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Are you sure in your ***wsgi.py*** file you have **app**  or it have **application** ?

Comment: Yes I have in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added threads to it, Problem solved for me

> --threads=3